# Best pattern to "view" special cases of immutable Objects

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, immutability

Say I have a hierarchy of immutable Objects like e.g. the the expressions of a programming language

```java
public abstract class Expression {}

public class IntConst extends Expression {
    public final Integer value;
    // ...
}

public class Variable extends Expression {
    public final String name;
    //...
}

public class Sum extends Expression {
    public final Expression child1;
    public final Expression child2;
    //... 
}

public class Product extends Expression {
    public final Expression child1;
    public final Expression child2;
    //... 
}
```

Now, in order to work with the objects of this hierarchy in some special cases, I want to have different (immutable) views on them. For example we could have a view `SimpleSum` which has a special `equals` that makes `a + 0` and `0 + a` and `a` equal or a view `SimpleProduct` that does something similar with `a * 1` and `1 * a` and `a`.

The way I have implemented it right now are static methods for each view, e.g.

```
public static Optional<SimpleSum> viewAsSimpleSum(Expression e) {
    if(isSimpleSum(e)) {
        return Optional.of(new SimpleSum(e));
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

public static boolean isSimpleSum(Expression e) {
    // cascade of "instanceof" or implementation via visitor
}
```

Since there are potentially many different views and algorithms (e.g. a mapping all "viewables" in a stream while leaving the "nonviewables" untouched) that are not dependent on the exact type of view, I would like to have some generic methods like `public static <E> Optional<E> viewAs(Expression e)` or `public static <E> boolean isViewableAs(Expression e)` in some helper class.  Unfortunately I have not succeeded so far (the only viable idea I had was throwing an exception from the constructor of the view, but this I don't find sufficiently pretty).

Is there a way to implement something like this in generically Java?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using java overriding.

For example:

```
public class Sum extends Expression {
    public final Expression child1;
    public final Expression child2;

    public Optional calculateSumm () {
      // perform simple calclation
    }
    //... 
 }

public class SimpleSum extends Sum {
    public Optional calculateSumm () {
       // perform simple calculation
    }
}

public class complexSum extends Sum {
   public Optional calculateSumm () {
       // perform complex calculation
   }
}
//--
```

Now in the the main class:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
     SimpleSum simple = new SimpleSum();
     ComplexSum complex = new ComplexSum();

    if(isSimpleSum(e)) {

       return simple.calculateSum();

    } else {
       return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```